# Como fazer com que dois divs fiquem com a mesma altura mesmo que tenham conteúdos de tamanho diferentes?

Tags: html, css

Olá,

Como posso deixar uma `<div>` com altura dinâmica, isso é, quando o `<div>` com o conteúdo dos produtos crescer o `<div>` que contém o menu também crescer junto, ficando os dois com a mesma altura?

Fiz algumas tentativas e não obtive sucesso, tenho isso:

A div que acomoda o meu menu:

```
<aside id="sidebar" class="one-fourth">
  <div class="widget">
    <h3>Selecionados:</h3>
    <nav>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row_rsDepartamento['descricao'];  ?> (<?php  echo $totalRows_rsProdutos; ?>)</a></li>
        <li class="current-menu-item"></li>                
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</aside>
```

A div que acomoda meus produtos:

```
<div class="team-member one-fourth"> 
  <a href="detalhes.php?produto=<?php echo $row_rsProdutos['id_produto']; ?>&dep=<?php echo $row_rsProdutos['id_departamento']; ?>&subdep=<?php echo $row_rsProdutos['id_subdepartamento']; ?>"><img class="photo" src="<?php echo $foto; ?>"  /></a>
    <div class="content">
      <h3 class="name"><?php echo $row_rsProdutos['descricao'];  ?> </h3>
      <span class="job-title"> <?php echo $row_rsProdutos['codigo_msb']; ?>     </span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

O css que tentei alterar ficaram assim:

```
#sidebar .widget {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 210px;
    min-height: 600px;
    height: auto;
}

.team-member {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.one-fourth {
    width: 23.5%;   
    max-width: 220px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Mas infelizmente não consegui resolver.

O site para uma demonstração pode ser encontrado aqui:
[Site](http://www.moveissaobento.com.br/msb/produtos.php?dep=2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Existem várias técnicas para fazer com que a altura de um `<div>` se ajuste automaticamente com a altura de outro. Uma das mais interessantes que vi ultimamente é essa: [Two Equal Height Columns Layout](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-2-column.htm).

Mas para o tipo de layout que você está criando aconselho usar uma técnica mais simples. Crie um `<div>` em volta dos produtos e aplique uma margem à esquerda do tamanho da sua barra lateral.

Exemplo:

```
<div class="team-wrapper">
    <div class="team-member one-fourth"> 
        <!-- Conteúdo do produto 1 -->
    </div>
    <div class="team-member one-fourth"> 
        <!-- Conteúdo do produto 2 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

E o CSS fica assim:

```
.team-wrapper {
    margin-left: 23.5%;
}
```

Espero que isso funcione para o que você quer fazer.

Comment: Olá @Jonatas Oliveira, primeiramente, muito obrigado pelas dicas, fiz como sugerido mas não obtive um resultado favorável.

Comment: Perdão pelo comentário anterior, refiz o código, agora devidamente correto e o resultado foi esplêndido. Muito obrigado.