# Como fazer para estes DIVs tenham a mesma altura, mas com seus conteúdos podem ser diferentes?

Tags: html, css, div

Como fazer os divs abaixo terem a mesma altura sempre?
O conteúdo é dinâmico, hora conteúdo do primeiro será maior, hora o do segundo, eu poderia usar tables, mas o conteúdo não é tabular.

```html
<div style="border: solid; height: 200px;">
  <div style="border: solid; display: inline-block;">
    DIV1 LINHA 1
  </div>
  <div style="border: solid; display: inline-block;">
    DIV2 LINHA 1
    <br> DIV2 LINHA 2
    <br> DIV2 LINHA 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer com que dois divs fiquem com a mesma altura mesmo que tenham conteúdos de tamanho diferentes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46299/como-fazer-com-que-dois-divs-fiquem-com-a-mesma-altura-mesmo-que-tenham-conte%c3%bado)

Comment: Pode ser com flex box? Vc está usando Bootstrap4?

Comment: Poderia criar uma classe única em css para ambas as div's e alterar a propriedade da altura conforme necessário.

Answer (score -1):

Acho que todas as confusões e dificuldades que eu tinha referentes à altura, posicionamento, responsividade, etc, puderam ser resolvidas com os modelos [deste link](https://css-tricks.com/accessible-simple-responsive-tables/)

Eu penso que a ideia de tabelas é muito mais intuitiva, mas obviamente é completamente obsoleta. Assim, neste link, ele consegue gerar classes que simulam uma tabela, mas com todas as vantagens do CSS.

Comment: Não vejo o uso de tabelas como obsoleta, mas como propósito, divs para divisões, tables para dados tabulares, o detalhe é que os divs não respondem como o esperado ao raciocínio humano, deve ser complexo programar o navegador para interpretar com div a vontade do usuário, por exemplo um float num objeto qualquer e o layout sai tudo zoado, ele não entende que o float é só pro objeto em si, ele reposiciona tudo após. O navegador parece fazer uma leitura direta e constante, pois a posição dos objetos seguem mais a sequencia do que a ordem.